# Caculate Logarithm in Solidity

Tags: solidity, logarithm

Is possible to caculate Logarithm in Solidity?
I have try to find but have no result.
Have any solution to caculate Logarithm in Solidity u guy? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMathQuad.sol

Also, [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/list-of-solidity-libraries-in-the-wild/2250) is a list Math libraries for solidity, so maybe you can find something there.

Comment: The function require bytes16 param, really complex to handle @@, do u know another library like that, huh @Niccolò Fant, thank you so much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math` library from openzeppelin.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/utils#Math

Answer (score 0):

For base 2 logarithm:

```
function log2(uint x) public pure returns (uint result) {
    while (x > 1) {
        x >>= 1;
        result++;
    }
}
```

For base 10 logarithm:

```
function log10(uint x) public pure returns (uint result) {
    while (x > 1) {
        x /= 10;
        result++;
    }
}
```

And finally for base N logarithm:

```
function logN(uint x, uint N) public pure returns (uint result) {
    while (x > 1) {
        x /= N;
        result++;
    }
}
```

Obviously this method calculates only integer part of logarithm. For calculating decimal parts, we must expand this solution.